# Can we keep discovered subtests in VSCode Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I really like we can run subtest in Testing pane except one issue that subtest will gone whenever I test code. We need to re-run whole tests to re-discover subtests. While I understand why vscode-go behave like this, this is also pretty inconvenient on debugging situation. Is there any hack to keep current subtests in Testing pane?

- Run a test
- VSCode discovers sub tests
- Run a sub test
- Debug and modify code
- All current discovered sub tests cleared

Comment: You can set a conditional break point so that it stops only when the condition is true. The condition can be something like `tc.name == "the sub test"`.